# We cannot send a text message to this phone number because its operator is not supported twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to create twitter developer account, so adding phone no at two factor auth page. but getting **We cannot send a text message to this phone number because its operator is not supported.**. I've a jio connection & I'm from India. what is the solution?

Answer (score -3):

Confirm that the phone number "40404" is not blocked on your phone.  This is one of the most commons causes of this error.